# Error: JSONObject["result"] is not a JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I am fetching a JSONObject "result" from the following JSONObject:

```
{
    "success" : true,
    "message" : "",
    "result" : {
            "uuid" : "e606d53c-8d70-11e3-94b5-425861b86ab6"
        }
}
```

I am using this code:

```
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    String url = "some url";
    HttpGet httpget20 = new HttpGet(url);
    httpget20.setHeader("apisign",buildHmacSignature(url, apisecret));
      try (   CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpget20)){
        HttpEntity entity = response2.getEntity();
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        JSONObject result = obj2.getJSONObject("result");
```

`obj2` is the whole json object including "success", "message" and "result".
However, this line of code generates the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["result"] is not a JSONObject.
```

I am not sure how a JSONObject can not be a JSONObject. Can someone explain the problem here?

Comment: can you add the minimal running code?

Comment: More code please!

Comment: Sure, I updated the question.

Comment: The json parsing part of your code is fine.  I expect that your problem is something having to do with getting the string out of the HttpEntity.  What string, exactly, does `EntityUtils.toString(entity)` return?

Comment: can you verify if obj2 is indeed the same as the one you posted?

Comment: A fact is that `EntityUtils.toString(entity)` is returning a valid JSON.  Can you validate what's string is returning that method?

Comment: The property "result" in your code is indeed, as others mentioned, an object. I suspect you are not getting exactly the same JSON string as posted. Could you **1)** post the result of `EntityUtils.toString(entity)`; **2)** post the result of `obj2.toString()`?

Comment: what is the output of `obj2.getJSONObject("result").getValueType()` ?

Comment: obj2.toString() returns:
{"result":null,"success":false,"message":"INVALID_SIGNATURE"}
EntityUtils.toString(entity) returns an IOException of a closed stream.
clearly the problem is that the "result" has a null value.

Comment: then do a check before blindly getting the result object

Comment: The thing is the same code before returned success as true and the problem persisted nonetheless.

Comment: it can be a different value other than jsonobject even it its success so still there is a problem

Answer (score 0):

[`JSONObject.getJSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)) can return a `JSONObject` only. It will not return `boolean`, `long` or `String`, and it will not return [`JSONObject.NULL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#NULL) in particular, because that is not a `JSONObject` itself (it says Java `Object` in the docs, and has a specific private type in the implementation).
Use [`isNull`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull(java.lang.String)) for checking it beforehand or just accept that it throws an exception and prepare for it. Of course you can also use the generic [`get`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#get(java.lang.String)) and check the result against `JSONObject.NULL` afterwards, perhaps use `instanceof`, just none of these will make the code simpler and all of them will introduce casting/casting attempts at some point.

I was linking the Android docs for readability, but you can of course dig into source code too, like [`getJSONObject`](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java#L731). You can find the `NULL` at the beginning of the same file if you are interested.